# L1 distance after Convolution

Tags: pr.probability, convolution

Given two discrete distributions $P$ and $Q$ with the same support $x_1,\cdots,x_n$. Assume $K \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is a nonnegative function with $\int_\mathbb{R} K(x)dx = 1$, and let $K_h(x) = \frac{1}{h}K(\frac{x}{h})$.

I am wondering whether the following result holds:
$$\left| \int_\mathbb{R} |P* K_h(x) - Q * K_h(x)|dx - \sum_i|P_i - Q_i| \right| \rightarrow 0, \quad as \, h\rightarrow 0 \, ?$$
where $P*K_h = \sum_i P_iK_h(x-x_i)$ is the convolution between $P$ and $K_h$. In other words, I would like $\left\Vert P*K_h - Q*K_h\right\Vert_1$ to be close to $\left\Vert P-Q\right\Vert_1$ when $h$ is small.

Actually we have that 
$$\int_\mathbb{R} |P* K_h(x) - Q * K_h(x)|dx \leq \sum_i|P_i - Q_i| \int K_h(x-x_i)dx = \sum_i|P_i - Q_i|,$$
but I do not know what is the case for the opposite direction.

I am also wondering will the same statement still hold when the $\ell_1$ distance is replaced with other distances, like Jensen–Shannon divergence.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely true, and the point is that for any two distinct $x\neq y\in \mathbb R$ the measures $\delta_x*K_h$ and $\delta_y* K_h$ are asymptotically singular as $h\to 0$, i.e.,
$$
\| \delta_x*K_h - \delta_y*K_h \| \to 2 \qquad \text{as}\quad h\to 0 \;.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree that they are asymptotically singular, but confused about the limiting value of 0. When h->0, do we have that | delta_x * K_h(z) - delta_y * K_h(z) | \approx K_h(z-x) + K_h(z-y) ? If this is true, then the integral $\int_R | delta_x * K_h(z) - delta_y * K_h(z) | dz = 2$ instead of goes to 0?

Comment: Ups - sorry - of course, the limit is 2 :)

Answer (score 0):

I would post this as a comment if I could:  is it not the case that if K also has compact support you get exact equality as soon as the support of K_h is contained is a small enough interval ?  E.g. if P and Q are Bernoulli with prop p and q of 1 resp. and K is uniform (-1/8, 1/8), then P*K is (1-p)*U(-1/8, 1/8)  + p * U(7/8, 9/8) and Q*K is (1-q)*U(-1/8, 1/8)  + q * U(7/8, 9/8), and $$ \int|P*K - Q*K| = 2|p-q| $$

Comment: Nice example. Indeed, if K has compact support, then as long as h is small enough,   the support K_h can be smaller than the minimal pairwise distance, this I guess is the critical value, among x_1,....,x_n, then we have the equality